# Authentication with the react-oidc-context library against Google does not work

Tags: reactjs, authentication, openid-connect, oidc-client-ts, react-oidc-context

I cannot authenticate with Google using the "react-oidc-context" library. I always get a HTTP 400 status from Google when the library tries to call the `/token` endpoint. This call is executed after the "Signin" button has been clicked.

```
<button type="button" onClick={() => auth.signinRedirect()}>
```

The error description is:

```
{
 error: "invalid_request", 
 error_description: "client_secret is missing"
}
```

The code I use is very similar to the code from the `react-oidc-context` documents.

```
<AuthProvider {...oidcConfig}>
   ... 
</AuthProvider>
```

My oidc config looks like:

```
const oidcConfig = {
  authority: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  client_id: '34534543543543',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:5173',
  scope: 'openid'
}
```

To be honest, I didn't understand why I need to configure the `client_secret` in a web application. That makes no sense to me. I have created an OAuth2.0 client of type 'Web' at Google.

Maybe someone can give me a tip.